# Sequentially chaining promises from 2 separate functions

Tags: javascript, promise, html-framework-7

I've reviewed all the related topics, but for some reason am unable to understand the correct syntax of resolving my case.
It's Javascript on Framework7 platform.

There is a function that has a $.each inside, which cycles through an array of items and executes an async POST operation to update that item.
There's a requirement to update items in two separate locations, so I execute this function twice, each time with a different arguments.

What would be the best approach to chain those two functions together in a sequence to be able to reload the page, as all async requests have been executed?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE!**

I managed to get this far, but promises.then doesn't result into "Success":

```
var tasks = [1,2,3];
var docs = [3,4,5];
var functions = [asyncOperation(tasks),asyncOperation(docs)]

var asyncOperation = function(items) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   var deferreds = [];
   items.forEach(function(i,e){
   deferreds.push(
       app.request({
       url: buildurlnew,
       type: "POST",
       headers: buildheader,
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(UpdatePayload),
       success: function (data) {},
       error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}
   )
   });
   return deferreds;
});
}

var promises = Promise.all(functions);
promises.then(function(results) {
//console.log("Success");
});
```

**UPDATE 2 - The changed code, as per suggestions**

```
var processtasks = function(array, dig) {
   var getlistname = GetItemTypeForListName("Alerts")
   var itemProperties = {'Title' :"Test"};
   var UpdatePayload = {'__metadata': {'type': getlistname}};
   for(var prop in itemProperties){
      UpdatePayload[prop] = itemProperties[prop]
   }
   var buildurl = "<REST URL to Sharepoint list>"
   var buildheader = { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest" : dig, "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE", "If-Match": "*"}
   return Promise.all(array.map(function(item) {
      buildurlnew = buildurl+"("+item+")";
      return app.request({
         url: buildurlnew,
         type: "POST",
         headers: buildheader,
         contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
         data: JSON.stringify(UpdatePayload),
         success: function (data) {},
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
      });
   }));
}

var processitems = function(listName, array, dig, type, source, web) {
   var getlistname = GetItemTypeForListName(listName)
   var buildurl = "<REST URL to Sharepoint list>"
   var buildheader = { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest" : dig, "If-Match": "*"}
   return Promise.all(array.map(function(item) {
      var itemProperties = {'UserId' : app.data.UserID, 'Title' : item};
      var UpdatePayload = {'__metadata': {'type': getlistname}};
      for(var prop in itemProperties){
         UpdatePayload[prop] = itemProperties[prop]
      }
      return app.request({
          url: buildurl,
          type: "POST",
          headers: buildheader,
          contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
          data: JSON.stringify(UpdatePayload),
          success: function (data) {},
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}
      });
   }));
}

processitems(listName, array, dig, type, source, web).then(function(r1) {
   return processtasks(ids,dig);
}).then(function(r2) {
   console.log(r2);
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: A programming language and what frameworks/platforms you are developing against would be useful here :P

Comment: If they can be run at the same time: `Promise.all([p1, p2])`. If one happens after the other: `p1.then(p2)`.

Comment: My apologies. I'm working ("trying to work" would actually be more accurate term for my position at this point) with Javascript on the Framework7 platform.

Comment: Your `new Promise` function never use `resolve` or `reject` on the array of promises that you create. you may start thinking from there. Yet you probably don't even need a promise constructor. Just return `Promise.all(deferred)`. So you may do like `asyncOperation(firstItems).then(resulsArray => (doSomethingWith(resultsArray), asyncOperation(secondItems))).then(doSomethingWith)` kind of.

Comment: What I'm currently confused about, is how to result into a single resolve from all those .forEach iterations inside each function?

Comment: What is `app.request()`?  What library is that from?

Comment: app.request() is the same $.ajax() inside the Framework7 environment.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to fix your `asyncOperation()` function because it is not properly returning a promise that is connected to the underlying async operations you're doing.

This code doesn't really make much sense.  You have a basic structure of this:

```
var asyncOperation = function(items) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // body of function here
    });
}
```

So far so good.  But, what you need to do inside that promise executor function is start some async operation and call resolve or reject when you're done.  You aren't doing that.  Therefore, your promise never resolves or rejects.

Instead, you are returning an array of deferreds from the promise executor callback which does nothing.  The promise executor function does not expect any return value so returning a value from it does nothing.  You have to indicate completion of your asynchronous operation in the promise executor by calling either `resolve(...)` or `reject(...)`.

If `app.request()` returns a promise, then you don't even need to make your own promise at all.  You can just do something like this:

```
var asyncOperation = function(items) {
    return Promise.all(items.map(function(item) {
        return app.request(...);
    }));
}

asyncOperation(...).then(function(results) {
    // all done here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

`items.map()` generates an array of promises and `Promise.all()` returns a new single promise that monitors that array of promise and will resolve when all the promises in the array resolve or reject when any one of them rejects.

---

If `app.request()` does not return a promise, then you probably should make a "promisified" version that does so you can use it with promise functions like `Promise.all()`, perhaps using `util.promisify()`.

---

To run two of these in parallel (which seems practical since they don't appear to depend upon one another), you could do this:

Then, once you are properly returning a promise for your function, if you have two of these, you can just use `Promise.all()` on more than one function call:

```
Promise.all([asyncOperation(...), asyncOperation(...)]).then(function(results) {
    // both done here
    // not the result may be an array of arrays
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

---

> What would be the best approach to chain those two functions together in a sequence

To run them in sequence, you can do this:

```
asyncOperation(args1).then(function(r1) {
    return asyncOperation(args2);
}).then(function(r2) {
    console.log(r2);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Added more info on handling two of these function calls.

Comment: Rewrote the app.request function as per your suggestion.
Created 2 separate app.request functions, since they both work with separate targets, and tried to chain them together in the following ways:

First:
`asyncOperation(args).then(asyncOperation(args2).then(function() {console.log("Success")}))`

Second:
`Promise.all([asyncOperation(args),asyncOperation(args2)]).then(function(results) {console.log("Success")}).catch(function(err) {console.log(err)});`

However, in both cases, console message "Success" is displayed already after the first function is completed.

Comment: @user3090296 - You aren't passing things to `.then()` properly.  You are calling `asyncOperation(args2)` immediately and then passing its return value to `.then()`.  You need to pass a function reference to `.then()` as in `asyncOperation(args).then(asyncOperation.bind(null, args2)).then(...)` or `asyncOperation(args).then(function() {return asyncOperation(args2)}.then(...)`

Comment: @user3090296 - I added an example of running them in sequence to the end of my answer.

Comment: First of all - huge thanks for helping me out with this.
However, tried with the example you added, and `console.log(r2)` is still returned before the `asyncOperation(args2)` is executed.

Comment: @user3090296 - That can only happen if `asyncOperation(args2)` is not returning a proper promise that is tied to it's async operation.  I've done all I can do with pseudo-code.  If you want further help, you will have to show the real code that you are now using and testing and having the problem with.  Your original code in your question showed you had issues with that, so I am assuming that there are still issues with that.

Comment: Updated the original post with all the related code blocks.